# httpd won't upgrade on RHEL 7: "Package(s) httpd available, but not installed."

Tags: apache, yum, rhel, rhel7

When I attempt to upgrade Apache...

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d && wget https://repo.codeit.guru/codeit.el7.repo
yum install -y epel-release
yum upgrade httpd
```

...the output says "Package(s) httpd available, but not installed."

Actually, the above commands worked fine on my staging server, and I got the desired upgrade. But then when I tried the same steps on my production server, I see "Package(s) httpd available, but not installed."

Variations of this issue appear elsewhere on stackoverflow and other forums, but it appears the proper solution changes frequently, and it is difficult to rely on past answers that in many cases appear to reference defunct mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where Apache was sourced from, but the recommended practice is to use Red Hat Software Collections for RHEL 7 (Application Streams for RHEL 8). See the list [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html-single/3.6_release_notes/index#sect-RHSCL-Features). If your Apache was installed from Software Collections, then you'd want to update via that process.

Software Collections are part of the subscription and are fully supported by Red Hat.

Comment: I don't understand Mike's answer, but this is probably due to my having limited experience with RedHat.  RedHat seems to involve some concepts, like "Software Collections," that don't apply to other Linux distributions. I will see if my boss will let me contact RedHat support.

Comment: Red Hat Software Collections are new versions of tools and technologies (including html server) that have a quicker release cadence that more aligns with the upstream communities. In RHEL 7, they're in a special repo for installation, etc. - you do need to enable the repo. See this link as an introduction: https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview.  See the Hello world section to explain the basics.  This is the formal doc page for them: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/